# Executing reducers by leftmost two digits of Mapper output key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Apache MapReduce to parse raw data and load it to a database.

My Mapper parses raw lines of data from text files - each line gets a unique numeric ID (key) and a collection of key-value pairs (value).

My Reducer saves, for each line ID, the key-value pairs on a database.

I want to group the line ID by the **leftmost two digits** - so that the reducers will process IDs that starts with 10, then 11, 12 etc.
I don't want any Reducer to run on IDs that start with 12, before all the reducers that process IDS that start with 11 has finished.

Can it be implemented using Apache  MapReduce?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like this is possible. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You can decide on number of reducers and one reducer for each ID 10, 11, 12. But you cannot make 12 wait for 11 as Map Reduce is designed for parallel processing and we can't have data based dependency withing single map reduce job.

You may probably try multiple MAP reduce jobs.

1. MAP ONLY JOB with 1 output for each ID
2. Schedule Your reducers manually or Oozie them in a way that JOb that
   process 11 Ids Runs before the JOb that process 12 Ids.

Hope it gives a way out.